# Drupal 7 Taxonomy Subscribe

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-taxonomy, drupal-forms

I need to create a subscription form. Subscriber shall select multiple taxonomies for which he wants to subscribe.
The best of what I saw was a plugin Simplenews. But it can not be selected multiple value.
Help please, which plug is able?
Thanks!

Comment: What you want to do with data submitted by users? Maybe webform module can do this job for you: https://www.drupal.org/project/webform

Comment: @MilanG Subscribe in taxonomy. When add node in taxonomy, user should be notified.